# How does someone use Guava's CacheLoader asynchronously

Tags: caching, guava

The question says it all I'd like to use CacheBuilder, but my values are pulled in asynchronously. This worked previously with MapMaker as the CacheLoader wasn't a requirement. Now I'd like to know if I can hack this up or if there are any non deprecated alternatives. Thank you.

Comment: The question really doesn't say it all. Could you explain more clearly what you were doing and why Cache won't work for you?

Comment: I'm guessing that you were using `MapMaker` to make a non-computing `ConcurrentMap`, which you would then populate via `map.put`. In Guava 10.0.1, you can do this with a `Cache` by using `cache.asMap().put`

Comment: @ColinD: The issue here is I need to pull a set of data asynchronously as a hole before being able to setup the cache, computing requires the hole set, I can't use cache on demand like this.

Comment: @Ray: How do I get a Cache implementation if it doesn't come from CacheBuilder? Unless I'm missing something, returning null in CacheLoader.load doesn't sound sane to me. Guess I can always make my own Cache from AbstractCache and make it happen.

Answer (score 5):

I think the question you're trying to ask is "How can I use CacheBuilder without having to specify a CacheLoader?" If that's the case, then there will be support for this in Guava release 11.0. In the meantime a build() method on CacheLoader is already checked into trunk (as of this morning):

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html

Comment: Yes, specifically in a process where the data is retrieved asynchronously which I still think is a valid use case. Thanks for you input.

Comment: Oh, if what you want is an asynchronous CacheLoader, then that's something we're talking about, but it won't happen anytime soon...

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to make with generic parameters K and V as your desired outputs:

```
LoadingCache<K, ListenableFuture<V>> values = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<K, ListenableFuture<V>>() {
         public ListenableFuture<V> load(K key) {
           /* Get your future */
         }
       });
```